# How to say "I was among the top ten percent of students" in my résumé?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Could you please tell me how I should mention this in my résumé (my personal website indeed) that I have graduated from the university, *while I was ranked among the top ten percent of students*?

For instance, is it OK to say:

> I was graduated from this university while I was among the top ten percent of the students"

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts - as you see, Neeku edited your question in the meantime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were in (or above) the 90th [percentile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/percentile).

Alternatively, you were in the 10th, or *top* [decile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/percentile) of your class or year.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but should I say "of year" or "of class" or ...?! Actually my resume is written in this way: "B.Sc in Civil Engineering - Oxford University - 2008-2012" ... Below this, I want to say that sentence as a brief description, and therefore, I don't want to repeat the name of the university again! For instance: "M.Sc in Earthquake Engineering - Stanford University - 2012-Present" (Description: I'm currently working on my thesis under the supervision of Associate Professor Massumi. Meanwhile, I have been recognized as an honors student for all semesters)

Comment: You should say "I graduated from Oxford University. I was among the top ten percent of students." as I explain in my answer.  To add more detail, like this:  "I graduated from Oxford University, with a _ _ _ in 2001. I was among the top ten percent of students."  it could not be simpler.

Answer (score 4):

*I graduated from Oxford University in the top 10% of my class.*

Short, sweet, to the point.

Comment: @ Joe Blow Thanks a lot, but should I say "of year" or "of class" or ...?! Actually my resume is written in this way: "B.Sc in Civil Engineering - Oxford University - 2008-2012" ... Below this, I want to say that sentence as a brief description, and therefore, I don't want to repeat the name of the university again! For instance: "M.Sc in Earthquake Engineering - Stanford University - 2012-Present" (Description: I'm currently working on my thesis under the supervision of Associate Professor Massumi. Meanwhile, I have been recognized as an honors student for all semesters)

Comment: In a resume, I'd likely drop the % sign and insert the word "percent." Call it a personal quirk of mine. Don

Comment: In a résumé, perhaps: *BS ... * / next line: *Graduated in the top ten percent of class* (assuming removal of I's and My's.)

Answer (score 0):

"I graduated at the top of my class from Oxford."

Comment: *At the top* and *in the top* are two different things. I doubt OP was valedictorian or he'd have said so instead of saying among the top 10%.

Comment: "At the top of my class" means I was "first", not (possibly) *seventh* or *ninth*.

Answer (score 0):

I was among the top of my class from Oxford.

Answer (score -3):

You you want to say "I was among the top ten percent of students," write it like this:

- “I was among the top ten percent of students.”

Regarding your other sentence, I wouldn't bother with the past tense. Also: never, ever for any reason use long sentences. Always chop every sentence, in to two short sentences.

So simply write:

- "I graduated from Oxford University. I was among the top ten percent of students."